# how to group by ranges in nhibernate with criteria api

Tags: nhibernate, criteria-api

I have sql that i would like to write in Criteria api:

```
SELECT CASE 
WHEN total_pages = 0 THEN '0 pages'
WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '1-3 pages'
WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4-6 pages'
WHEN total_pages > 6 THEN '7 + pages'
END AS pagerange, sum(total_pages) AS 'Total'
FROM dbo.connector_log_entry
GROUP BY 
CASE 
WHEN total_pages = 0 THEN '0 pages'
WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '1-3 pages'
WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4-6 pages'
WHEN total_pages > 6 THEN '7 + pages'
END
ORDER BY pagerange
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var groupBy = @"
    CASE
      WHEN total_pages = 0 THEN '0 pages'
      WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN '1-3 pages'
      WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN '4-6 pages'
      WHEN total_pages > 6 THEN '7 + pages'
    END";
var pagerange = Projections.SqlGroupProjection(groupBy + " pagerange",
                                               groupBy,
                                               new[] { "pagerange" },
                                               new[] { NHibernateUtil.String });
var results = session.CreateCriteria<ConnectorLogEntry>()
                     .SetProjection(pagerange,
                                    Projections.Sum("TotalPages"))
                     .List();
```

This assumes your class is called `ConnectorLogEntry` and the property mapped to the total_pages column is called `TotalPages`.

I owe you the ORDER BY bit, but you can always sort client-side.

Comment: I ended up with almost exact same code myself. And order by works good also. one thing that i added is var caseString =
                @"CASE 
                WHEN total_pages = 0 THEN 'a0 pages'
                WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'b1-3  pages'
                WHEN total_pages BETWEEN 4 AND 6 THEN 'c4-6  pages'... alphabet letters to PageRanges for good sorting